# JCE not appearing for custom front-end user-groups

Tags: acl, jce, bugs, front-end

For whatever reason, I can't make the **JCE Editor** appearing for my **custom usergroups** in **front-end**.

I have tried so many combinations and still can't make it work.

At the moment I have ended up with only the **Default JCE Profile**, assigned to all the groups except the guest group and I also gave extended JCE permissions to these groups.

But still the editor (in front-end) will display only to groups that have backend access and not to those that have only front-end access.

I have checked it also with the **[ACL manager](http://aclmanager.net/)** but I didn't noticed anything apparently wrong... 
Another thing to note is that there are no any JS conflicts that could cause any issues.

Is it possible that I am missing something obvious, ACL related, or a setting somewhere that manages editor access to the front-end?

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in with a user that belongs to one of these groups? Silly question but I only ask because it has happened to me before

Comment: well good point, let me check once again... but during my troubleshooting, I am sure I have assigned the jce to all usergroups, that includes those I was testing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guys after messing around with the ACL in all other places, and checking for any kind of possible other issues for some hours, finally I managed to sort this out.

The issue was caused by the **ACL settings** on the **JCE Editor plugin**, which is being called when it comes to load the editor.
It had access level to Administrator, so any front-end users were unable to get access and load the editor.
I set its access to **Public** and now I have the editor loading on Front-end for all my usergroups.